# How to Publish UWP Project as Single installer file

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, appx

I want to Publish a UWP project because I do not have a certificate, I can not publish inside the store. As far as I know, I need to create an appxbundle file. I can see that [winget-cli](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/tag/v1.0.11451) use the single appxbundle file. But I do not find any options in Visual Studio or Documentation.
How can I publish my project as appxbundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you have a developer account, then you could publish your app to the store and the certificate will be automatically generated by the store.

If you don't want to publish your app to the store and you just want to distribute your app by yourself, you could still use Visual Studio to package your app like this: [Create an app package using the packaging wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-using-the-packaging-wizard).

Comment: no idont have any developer account, i know how to generate package, but As I said, Visual Studio does not create a single package file but all their products are in a single package

Comment: No, packaging using Visual Studio is different.  When you tried to generate a sideload package in Visual Studio, the package file is the file that you are looking for.  The whole folder contains other files like install script, certificates and dependencies. But the app package is what you want.

Comment: thank you, I tried it now, it seems crating and the signing process is a bit complicated, is there an easier way to sign it? For example, an application with a user interface instead of command line

Comment: @Atena Because you are distributing your app via sideloading, then users must install your certificate first.  If you don't want to use the script to install, you have to install the certificate manually by double click the certificate file and choose the correct location to install the certificate. Only after installing the certificate, the app package could be installed.

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant, i tested App Packager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/make-appx-package--makeappx-exe-#to-sign-the-package-using-signtool and this is what i want, But there is a problem, the developer has to create the cer file and finally sign the installer file. These steps are a bit complicated. The documentation is not clear enough (at least I do not understand)

Comment: First of all, the document you posted targets the win32 apps not for the UWP apps.  If your app is UWP app, you need to check this document-[Create an MSIX package or bundle with MakeAppx.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool). There are also documents about how to create certificates for UWP apps on the same document archives, you could check the document menu on the left.